# invalid keyword argument for int()

Tags: python-3.x, types

I have tried without the type, with float - what is my newby mistake here?

```
def calcAge(age):
    return int(birth=20 - age)

age = int(input("What age will you turn this year? "))
birth = int(calcAge(age))
```

RESULT:

```
What age will you turn this year? 54

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/DSDJ/My files/ParameterPassReturnTest.py", line 13, in <module>
  birth = int(calcAge(age))
File "D:/DSDJ/My files/ParameterPassReturnTest.py", line 8, in calcAge
  return int(birth=20 - age)
TypeError: 'birth' is an invalid keyword argument for int()

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The int call is a function. By saying "birth=20-age" you are basically saying, "The argument birth is (20-age)". The function is looking for that argument but cannot find it and that is why you get that error. Just do

```
def calcAge(age):
    return 20 - int(age)

age = int(input("What age will you turn this year? "))
birth = calcAge(age)
```

Comment: wow - adding a question in a suitable format was a learning curve, adding a comment is whole new story - thanks for your help - it is working perfectly now.

Comment: @GailWittich no problem

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on this line:

```
return int(birth=20 - age)
```

`int()` is a method that takes an argument. You're giving it a named argument `birth`, but that's not what it expects. Remove the name, to this, gets you closer:

```
return int(20 - age)
```

Unfortunately `age` is not an int. I think what you want is this:

```
return 20 - int(age)
```

You can then remove the `int()` call a few lines later.

Comment: wow - adding a question in a suitable format was a learning curve, adding a comment is whole new story - thanks for your help - it is working perfectly now.